# Why are these two images that are the same size not displaying as the same size?

Tags: import, image

The picture below is what my code is as well as the outputs (I covered the faces in MS paint for privacy). Both of the pictures are 160x200 px JPEGs, so I've really got no idea why they wouldn't print at the same size.

[image]

Comment: In order to help, we're going to need to be able to access the two images...

Comment: If you have M12.1, the images likely have different resolutions (pixels / physical length unit). Evaluate `Options[img]` to see if there's a resolution tag.

Comment: @Szabolcs they do have different resolutions, and I was able to fix the problem! Thanks so much!